# Facebook login close my activity

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I am trying to integrate the Facebook login in my Android application.
I am using the last Facebook Sdk downloaded by gradle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

Here is my code:

```
public class SocialLogin extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "SocialLogin";

CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_social_login);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login attempt success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login attempt canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

The Facebook SDK shows correctly the activity to accept the requested permission, but in the meanwhile, the **onDestroy()** method of my Activity is called by someone. This means that the application is already closed when you accept the required permissions, and the **onActivityResult** is never called.
Sadly, logcat doesn't show anything useful.

Just if I restart my application and i click again on the Facebook Login Button, the onActivityResult method is invoked.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Does it  forcestopped ?? Post ur log

Comment: @RissmonSuresh please read my edit

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered this problem. It turns out, it was my fault because I had the `noHistory` flag on my activity so `onActivityResult` will never get called

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, I using this code almost all in my apps and perfectly working..

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

loginButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday"));

loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), (object, response1) -> {
                    Log.i("FACEBOOK",object.toString());
                    externalRegister(object);
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender,first_name,last_name");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login attempt canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Then add callback in *onActivityResult()*

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but it doesn't solve my problem. Please, read my edit for more information.